# How to keep line breaks in a txt readme file when zipped by addfile in php?

Tags: php, zip, line, break

I have a txt file showing copyright info and address to be zipped together with my images. I use php to do that. All works fine but when opening the ReadMe.txt after downloading the zip, all linebreaks are gone. How to keep the line breaks? The code I use:

```
    $date = date("y-m-d");
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$download =  'pics-' . $date . '.zip';
$zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob("photos/*.jpg") as $file) { /* Add appropriate path to read content of zip */
$new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
$zip->addFile($file,$new_filename);
    //$zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->addFile('/info/readme.txt', 'ReadMe.txt');
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $download");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($download));
header("Location: $download");
```

Comment: Did you really check with an hexeditor? It's not uncommon for plain line feeds to not be visible where CR LFs are expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following

```
foreach (glob("photos/*.jpg") as $file) { /* Add appropriate path to read content of zip */
$new_filename = substr($file,strrpos($file,'/') + 1);
$file=$new_filename."<br />"

$zip->addFile($file);
}
```